# how to determine the stability of three species model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i am working on a three species predator prey model so there are three eigenvalues. in line with this, ive encountered eigenvalues zero with multiplicity two and a nonzero eigenvalue. my question is how to determine the stability of the equilibrium solution if that is the case.

Comment: To determine the stability of the equilibrium solution of a two species model with an eigenvalue zero is easy? Sure about that?

Comment: Yes. If one of the eingenvalue is always zero and the other one is positive then the equilubrium is unstable, while if the other is negative then it is stable but not asymprotically stable. And if in case the other eigenvalue is also zero then the system undergoes steady state bifurcation. Bur the analysis on the three species model is different.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot follow you. See answer below.

Comment: Did you clear the misconceptions explained in my answer before offering a bounty? (Did you even *react* to said answer, to begin with?) Right, I thought not...

Answer (score 2):

> Quote: *If one of the eigenvalues is zero and the other one is negative then (the equilibrium) is stable but not asymptotically stable.*

This is wrong on both counts.

The differential system $$x'=\dfrac{x^3}{1+x^2},\qquad y'=-y,$$ has an equilibrium at $(0,0)$ with eigenvalues $-1$ and $0$. For every initial conditions $(x(0),y(0))$ such that $x(0)\ne0$, $|x(t)|\to+\infty$ when $t\to\infty$.

Thus, **the equilibrium $(0,0)$ is not stable** although *one of the eigenvalues is zero and the other one is negative*.

The differential system $$x'=-\dfrac{x^3}{1+x^2},\qquad y'=-y,$$ has an equilibrium at $(0,0)$ with eigenvalues $-1$ and $0$. For every initial conditions $(x(0),y(0))$, $(x(t),y(t))\to(0,0)$ when $t\to\infty$.

Thus, **the equilibrium $(0,0)$ is asymptotically stable** although *one of the eigenvalues is zero and the other one is negative*.

Comment: You did not answer my question. :(

Comment: Seriously? If already in dimension 2, the criterium you envision is inconclusive, do you think it might become conclusive in dimension 3?